# Perception and Perspective

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-usage, word-difference

I don't clearly understand the difference between perception of a human and perspective of a human. And "perception for perspective" phrase is right or "perspective for perception" is right?

Comment: Your ***perception*** is effectively ***something you see***, whereas your ***perspective*** is ***the position*** (literal "vantage point", or metaphoric "attitude, preconception") ***from which you see something***. Note that regardless of whether it might have a potentially useful meaning (which I'm not necessarily convinced of), the collocations *perception for perspective* and *perspective for perception* are both hopelessly "clumsy", and would probably be avoided by native speakers.

Comment: The two phrases "perception for perspective" and "perspective for perception" don't seem to have any meaning to my ear. If someone decided to use one of these phrases, they would have to explain it or give it enough context. These words are similar enough that many native English speakers would have trouble explaining the difference.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham: Per my first comment, I'd have though *all* halfway-competent native speakers would understand the general difference between ***perspective*** and ***perception***. OP's two suggested collocations just toggle which is the "main" noun, and which simply "qualifies" that primary object. The "problem" comes when you try to figure out why anyone would have any reason to explicitly provide *either* of those qualifications (what useful extra *meaning* might they impart?).

Comment: perspective goes to the visual, and, by extension, the point of view; perception goes to the senses and the mind. Neither phrase is "right". A human being can have a perception of something or a perspective about/on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **perception** is your ability to perceive and your **perceptions** are what you have perceived. A single thing which you have perceived is **a perception**.

**Perceive**, the verb which underlies the noun perception, can refer either to the body getting sensory impressions  (sight, taste, hearing, smell, touch)  or to the mind understanding the world.

**Perspective** is the angle from which you perceive, based on your point of view. Point of view can be literal:

> From the perspective of the high-rise roof, I could see the entire neighborhood.

or it can be figurative:

> From my perspective as a health-care professional, I see this policy as a step backwards.

Comment: I understood the meaning of perspective, but can you explain perception as well?

Answer (score 1):

Literally, a *perception* is how something registers on your senses.

It's often also used to mean "your judgement on X based on outwardly observable traits" which may include things like history of behavior, works produced in the past by a person, etc.

Literally, a *perspective* is a specific view from a specific angle.

It's also used to mean an understanding of how X fits in to a wider picture.

Perspectives provide additional information which can complete or alter perceptions.

Here is an example:

> I saw John steal food from the grocery store.

Perception: John is a thief.  Thieves are bad people, so John is a bad person.

Perspective: Wider picture - I know John is homeless and hasn't eaten in three days.  He stole property but did it because he was desperate, so he may not be a bad person.

> And "perception for perspective" phrase is right or "perspective for perception" is right?

Neither of these are well known phrases.  They both can be right depending on what you want to say.

Comment: I think by choosing to illustrate ***perspective*** with that extremely metaphoric "wider picture" example you're effectively blurring the clear-cut distinction between literal ***perspective*** and ***perception***. When used metaphorically, it seems to me both terms tend to converge on a semantic area perhaps more accurately expressed using the word ***context***.

Comment: I am sorry but i got more confused by your given example!